# Can't delete a Non-empty S3 bucket and Log group on deletion of CFN stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When I delete a cloudformation stack, it doesn't delete the non empty s3 bucket with it and non-empty log group with it.

Any idea why is it so? And how can I override deleting it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non empty S3 buckets cannot be deleted, neither by CloudFormation nor by the API.

To avoid CloudFormation errors when deleting a stack containing a non empty bucket, you can set the [`DeletionPolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) to `Retain`.

If you effectively want to empty your bucket before deleting it, it can be achieved with a [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html). Basically, you will have a Lambda function empty your bucket during a delete event (your custom resource will reference, `Ref`, your bucket in order for this to work).

Non empty CloudWatch Log Groups can be deleted. You shouldn't see any errors.